# Map of field name as key and value as value

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, field

I would like to create Map<String, Double> when as keys there will be names of declared fields of class, and as value - value of that field:
For example:

```
class Car {
    private double price;
    private long vmax;
}
```

```
Map<{price, 100000}, {vmax, 200}>
```

I know how to "iter" by fields but I can not get that value:

```
public Map<String, Double> convert(Object object) {
    Map<String, Double> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field declaredField : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
       declaredField.setAccessible(true);
       parameters.put(declaredField.getName(), (Double) declaredField.get(object));
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

Comment: What is the `object`?

Comment: _"I can not get that value"_: what do you mean here?

Comment: object is for example Car which i put in method parameter

Comment: If by chance you are trying to serialize your bean, this library may make you a lot faster: http://genson.io/GettingStarted/#pojo-databinding

Answer (score 1):

The error you experience is `ClassCastException`:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double
> ```

This is obvious as you try to cast `long vmax` into `Double` through the following snippet:

```
(Double) declaredField.get(object)
```

Though the declared field name is `String`, the field's value cannot be determined and casting is required. The wanted type is never guaranteed. In the case of `double price`, it can be cast into `Double`, but it is not for `long vmax`.

You want to change the map generics and casting to `Map<String, Number>` or rather `Map<String, Object>` that would be safer.

```
public static Map<String, Object> convert(Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    for (Field declaredField : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        declaredField.setAccessible(true);
        parameters.put(declaredField.getName(), declaredField.get(object));
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

For sample instance `new Car(15d, 25L)`, the map would result as `{price=15.0, vmax=25}`.